# cin.fail with extra conditions C++

Tags: c++

So I need to get input from the user which has to be a number and I have to use `cin.fail()` to check if it is a number. On top of that, the number has to be either 0, 1 or 2. I'm new to C++ so haven't figured out how to do it.

Here's the part of the code. It checks if the input is a number, but I do't know how to make it check if the number is 1, 2 or 0 and if not then ask again until the input is valid.

```
do {
  input = false;
  cout << "Enter a number from the menu: ";
  cin >> menu;

  if (cin.fail()) {
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    input = true;
    cin.clear();
  }
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

} while (input);

cout << "Valid input!";
```

Comment: you can check the menu value with a "if" : if (menu >= 0 && menu <=2)

Comment: Depends on what `menu` is? Probably an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `menu` is an integer, witch makes sense, you can add the conditions you mentioned to your `if`:

```
if (cin.fail() || menu < 0 || menu > 2)
```

[Live sample](https://onlinegdb.com/HkoAv90QI)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable `menu` is a string ,you can take the first character of the string `menu` in the if statement and check if the decimal value of the character is between the decimal number of `'0'` to `'3'`.

Change your if statement to this:

```
if (menu[0] < '0' || menu[0] > '3' || menu.length() > 1)
{
    // Error code
}
```

This code will run only if the decimal value of the first character is smaller than the decimal value of the char `'0'` or bigger than the decimal value of the char `'3'` and this code will run if the length of the input the user entered is bigger than 1.

Comment: Why do you assume that `menu` is a string? If it is, it's a good answer.

Comment: @churill It wasn't mentioned there so I assumed that. I could be wrong, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 'menu' has to be a integer so this won't work for me. thanks anyway!